# How to change yes/no in a column to 1 and 0

Tags: r

I have  column in R with Yes and No and I need to convert the no into 0 and the yes into 1 
So far I have

```
clean %>% mutate(flight=ifelse(flight=="NO", 0,1))
```

However, it turns out that some of the values are 'N', 'n' or 'no' which are all being converted into 1. How do I convert all those variants into 0 as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we need to convert multiple values "N", "n", "no", "NO" and all others as "Yes" to 0 and 1, get the first character with `substr`, change it to upper case (`toupper`, do a comparison (`!=`) with "N" and coerce it to binary (`as.integer`)

```
library(dplyr)
clean %>%
       mutate(flight = as.integer(toupper(substr(flight, 1, 1)) != "N"))
```

NOTE: Assume that there are only "Yes", "NO", "no", "N", "n" as values in the column

#### data

```
clean <- tibble(flight = c("No", "Yes", "YES", "Y", "no",
      "No", "NO", "Y", "n", "y", "No"))
```

Comment: what if some of the yes columns had y, would that still work?

Comment: @helpimlost  Yes, it would work because we are getting all the `No` options as "N"`

Answer (score 2):

Use conditional `|` in `grepl()` search

```
library(tidyverse)

clean <- 
  tibble(
    flight = 
      c("No", "Yes", "YES", "Y", "no", "No", "NO", "Y", "n", "y", "No"))

clean %>% 
  mutate(
    flight = 
      ifelse(
        test = grepl(pattern = "N|n", x = flight), 
        yes = 0, 
        no = 1))
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `substr`, you can also use `startswith` like follows:

```
library(dplyr)
clean <- tibble(flight = c("No", "Yes", "YES", "Y", "no",
                           "No", "NO", "Y", "n", "y", "No"))
clean %>% mutate(flight = as.integer(x = startsWith(tolower(flight), "y")))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using sample data from @akrun, a different `dplyr` and `grepl()` possibility could be:

```
clean %>%
 mutate(temp = (!grepl("n",  flight, ignore.case = TRUE)) * 1)

   flight
    <int>
 1      0
 2      1
 3      1
 4      1
 5      0
 6      0
 7      0
 8      1
 9      0
10      1
11      0
```

Or the same with just `base R`:

```
clean$flight <- (!grepl("n",  clean$flight, ignore.case = TRUE)) * 1
```

Or:

```
clean %>%
 mutate(flight = as.integer(!grepl("n", flight, ignore.case = TRUE)))
```

Or the same with just base R:

```
clean$flight <- as.integer(!grepl("n",  clean$flight, ignore.case = TRUE))
```